# Locally Finite-Component Space?

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist in literature the notion of a "locally finite-component space"? That is, some topological space $X$ such that for all $x \in X$, there exists some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ has a finite number of connected components? What about a finite number of path components?

The closest thing I've seen so far is that $X$ is *locally path-connected* if and only if every open subset of $X$ has open connected components (which are also precisely the path-connected components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from J. Väisälä's book "Lectures on n-dimensional quasiconformal mappings":

> Let $D$ be a domain in $\overline{\mathbb R}^n$ and let $b\in \partial D$. [...] $D$ is *finitely connected* at $b$ if $b$ has arbitrarily small neighborhoods $U$ such that $U\cap D$ has a finite number of components.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something suitable from Munkres's *Topology*; $X$ is "locally finite (path-)component" according to my definition if and only if the partition $X/\sim$ is *locally finite*, where $\sim$ is the (path-)connectivity equivalence relation.